# How to do an iterative email send with breaks for user prompts?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, while-loop, outlook

I have VBA code that iterates through emails in an Excel file and populates the bodies of Outlook emails with different criteria that relate to the recipients of the emails.

I want after each automated creation/draft of an email to wait with the draft email open for the user to manually check then send the email.  The program would then continue by drafting the next email and prompting the user to check it before sending it.

I am wondering if you can have a While loop within a For loop.
The For loop iterates until all emails have been sent.
The While loop gets its criteria from Outlook. "Did the user send the email? Yes? Draft the next one".

I could not find any resources online. I don't have any code. This question is for directional help. Do you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do would be difficult to architect with VBA but not impossible. I would recommend a COM add-in. Regardless, there's no concept of a wait cycle in Outlook that would work in your favor.  You will need to maintain a collection of Inspector windows that you add to or remove based on the Inspectors.NewInspector and Inspector.Close events (this is known to Outlook devs as a "wrapper model").  From those Inspector objects you can obtain the MailItem object from Inspector.CurrentItem, and from there you can trap the MailItem.Send event which you can cancel based on user review or proceed to set some internal variables that you can track for managing these send events you're monitoring.

If the wrapper model is too complex, you can just trap single instances of when those events fire, but new windows would fire the event anew and you would lose your "connection" to the item.

For general VBA help, see the [Outlook Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/vba/api/overview/Outlook/object-model) documentation or [OutlookCode.com](http://www.outlookcode.com) (old but still relevant).